# Extract multiple 7z files with auto rename

Tags: bash, 7zip

I have a bunch of 7z files, some of which contain files that have the same name. Therefore, I would like to do auto rename.

I can do something like

```
find ./all -exec 7z x -pabc123 -oall/xml {} \;
```

to extract all the files, but this asks me for each archive whether or not I want to auto rename them. Is there a way I can just have it ask me once? Or better yet, pass that in as a command line option?

(Note that I have to use seven zip because it has a password.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [p7zip manual](http://7zip.bugaco.com/7zip/MANUAL/switches/overwrite.htm):

> ### `-ao` (Overwrite mode) switch
>
> Specifies the overwrite mode during extraction, to overwrite files
>   already present on disk.
>
> #### Syntax
>
> ```
> -ao[a | s | t | u ]
> ```
>
> #### Switch    Description
>
> `-aoa`    Overwrite All existing files without prompt.
>   `-aos`    Skip extracting of existing files.
>   `-aou`    aUto rename extracting file (for example, `name.txt` will be renamed to `name_1.txt`).
>   `-aot`    auto rename existing file (for example, `name.txt` will be renamed to `name_1.txt`).
>
> #### Examples
>
> ```
> 7z x test.zip -aoa
> ```
>
> extracts all files from `test.zip` archive and overwrites existing files without any prompt.
>
> #### Commands that can be used with this switch
>
> [`e` (Extract)](http://7zip.bugaco.com/7zip/MANUAL/commands/extract.htm),
>   [`x` (Extract with full paths)](http://7zip.bugaco.com/7zip/MANUAL/commands/extract_full.htm)
>
> #### See also
>
> Switches: [`-y` (assume Yes on all
>   queries)](http://7zip.bugaco.com/7zip/MANUAL/switches/yes.htm)

Looks like either the `-aou` or the `-aot` switch on the `7z` command will do what you want, e. g.:

```
find all -exec 7z x -aou [OPTIONS...] {} \;
```